# Как автоматически переносить текст нижнего дива, чтобы он (текст) не заезжал под картинку?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Ниже фрагмент кода страницы сайта на Bootstrap 4. Как автоматически переносить текст нижнего дива, чтобы он (текст) не заезжал под картинку?

```
<div class="profile-picture profile-picture-lg tile-left">
    <img href="" src="assets/img/very.jpg">
</div>      <br><br>    
<div class="tile-right">
    <p class="lead font-bold text-right"><b>Veritasium</b></p>
    <p>videos about science, <br>education, and<br> anything else.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Не то чтобы было понятно о чем Вы говорите. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: К тому же, к Bootstrap 4 имеют отношение только эти 2 класа `lead text-right` и все.